# Installing multiple nuget packages by manually editing the packages.config

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I need to install a bunch of packages on multiple projects, and it would be nice to not have to manually look them all up in each project and install them one by one. Is it possible to add this to a packages.config and run some sort of update command?

```
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.AssemblyName" version="1.0.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Memory" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Settings.AppSettings" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Console" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.File" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

I tried to run `Update-Package –reinstall -projectName MyProject` but it just removed the packages I added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the packages where never installed, you can not update them. You need to install the packages first:

E.g.

```
Install-Package Serilog
```

More information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell

Comment: Just to be clear, the only option is to run the `Install-Package` command for each package?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I could unload a project and copy these lines from the first .csproj file into the second. This saved my from having to run the Install-Package command an ungodly number of times.

```
 <Reference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.AssemblyName, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Enrichers.AssemblyName.1.0.9\lib\net461\Serilog.Enrichers.AssemblyName.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Enrichers.Environment.2.1.3\lib\net45\Serilog.Enrichers.Environment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Memory, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7bed4405496f503, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Enrichers.Memory.1.0.4\lib\net45\Serilog.Enrichers.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Process, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Enrichers.Process.2.0.1\lib\net45\Serilog.Enrichers.Process.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Enrichers.Thread.3.1.0\lib\net45\Serilog.Enrichers.Thread.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Compact, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Formatting.Compact.1.1.0\lib\net452\Serilog.Formatting.Compact.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Settings.AppSettings, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Settings.AppSettings.2.2.2\lib\net45\Serilog.Settings.AppSettings.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Sinks.Console.3.1.1\lib\net45\Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Sinks.File.4.1.0\lib\net45\Serilog.Sinks.File.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.2.3.0\lib\net45\Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Serilog.Sinks.Seq.4.0.0\lib\net45\Serilog.Sinks.Seq.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```